# Windows Store App: How to make ListView with expandable/enlargeable ListItems?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, touch, windows-store-apps

I have a Listview with items, in a C# Windows Store App (is that what you call these? I heard they're not called Metro Apps anymore).

Similar to the [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) in Android, I want to be able to **tap on listitems** (not the buttons) for that listitem to expand, **tap on the expanded listitem** for it to collapse, and if you tap on another listitem, the currently expanded listitem will collapse and the other will expand.

In my particular case I have a `DataTemplate` for both the expanded and non-expanded view of the listitems. I've seen that Android's ExpandableListView can expand the listitem with *additional* information (the [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx) from WPF does something similar to that), instead of **replacing it with a larger item**, but is there a common solution for this in Windows Store Apps?
If not, what is the closest equivalent?

Like on the following drawing, I want to know if there is a component that can expand listitems in this way, or if not, which alternatives I have:
[image: Drawing of Expandable-ListItem in Windows Store App]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up with a solution that works but doesn't look too fancy. It switches `DataTemplate` when you click items but there's no animation: it switches instantly.

Here's the important code parts:

### XAML

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dtSmall">
        <!--Component template for the un-expanded listitems-->
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dtEnlarged">
        <!--Component template for the expanded listitems-->
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lvEnlargeable"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtSmall}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"
        SelectionChanged="LVEnlargeable_SelectionChanged"
        ItemClick="LVEnlargeable_ItemClick"/>
</Grid>
```

### XAML.CS

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private DataTemplate dtSmall;
    private DataTemplate dtEnlarged;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        dtSmall = (DataTemplate)Resources["dtSmall"];
        dtEnlarged = (DataTemplate)Resources["dtEnlarged"];
    }

    // A selected item is treated as an expanded/enlarged item
    private void LVEnlargeable_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* First we set all the items that has been deselected
        to be collapsed, aka. using the dtSmall DataTemplate.
        We expect 0 or 1 item to have been deselected
        but handle all cases easily with a foreach loop.
        */
        foreach (var item in e.RemovedItems)
        {
            // Set the DataTemplate of the deselected ListViewItems
            ((ListViewItem)(sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(item)).ContentTemplate = dtSmall;
        }

        /* Then we set all the items that has been selected
        to be expanded.
        We should probably throw an Exception if more than 1 was found,
        because it's unwanted behavior, but we'll ignore that for now.
        */
        foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
        {
            ((ListViewItem)(sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(e.AddedItems[0])).ContentTemplate = dtEnlarged;
        }
    }

    /* We need click events because SelectionChanged-events
    cannot detect clicks on an already selected item */
    private void LVEnlargeable_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView lv = (sender as ListView);

        /* Having set the IsItemClickEnabled property on the ListView to True
        we have to handle selection events manually.
        If nothing is selected when this click occurs, then select this item*/
        if (lv.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            lv.SelectedItem = e.ClickedItem;
        }
        else
        {
            // Clicking on an expanded/selected/enlarged item will deselect it
            if (lv.SelectedItem.Equals(e.ClickedItem))
            {
                lv.SelectedItem = null;
            }
            else
            {   /* If it's not a selected item, then select it
                    (and let SelectionChanged unselect the already selected item) */
                lv.SelectedItem = e.ClickedItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested if this isolated code is enough, on its own, for this solution, but I hope it is, and this code at least contain the key points. It's late and I just wanted to post something for the curious-minded people. If this shows not to work for you, then please leave a comment about the issue and I'll make sure to add the missing parts.

I also messed with the ListViewItemStyleContainer's ListViewItemPresenter to have better selection effects etc. but I figure it's best to keep it short. If you find this interesting as well, then feel free to leave a comment for that too, and I'll try include it.